# Ajax Json Symfony 2

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

I'm getting an ajax failed when working with symfony2 in ajax.

Any ideas?

HTML

```
              $.ajax({
                  url: "{{ path('destination_app_ajax') }}",
                     type: "post",
                     data: {
                         "json" : JsonData
                     },
                     success: function(JsonData){  
                          $('#result').html(JsonData);

                          /* Clear all Data */  
                          JsonData = "";
                          localStorage.clear();
                          alert("Data Sent!");

                     },
                      error:function(){
                          alert('ajax failed');    
                      }   
                });
```

**Controller**

```
public function ajaxAction(){

    $json = json_encode($_POST);

    return new Response(array('json' => $json));


}
```

Comment: Just a comment but you should have a look at the `JsonResponse` object class in Symfony2. more useful than manually encoding your response, and it sets appropriate headers etc. Additionally, you should look further into what error status you are getting from the server on the jQuery side - `jQuery.ajax().error()` has the following method signature: `Type: Function(jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown)`. A status code can go a long way in debugging...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response should look like this:

```
public function ajaxAction(){

    $json = json_encode(array('json' => $_POST));

    return new Response($json, 200, array('Content-Type'=>'application/json'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks man I had to also add use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response; to top

Comment: Sure, that goes without saying. If you use object, add use statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
echo  json_encode(array('json' => $_POST));
```

Script:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ path('destination_app_ajax') }}",
           type: "post",
           data: {
               "json" : JsonData
           },
           success: function(data){  
                $('#result').html(data.json);
                /* Clear all Data */                    
                localStorage.clear();
                alert("Data Sent!");

           },
            error:function(){
                alert('ajax failed');    
            }   
      });
```